# Include meta properties in Facebook Share Dialog Image

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Share Dialog to share a image from our amazon s3 bucket to Facebook

```
       ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle(name)
                .setContentDescription(description)
                .setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL) //from amazon s3 
                .setContentUrl(deepLinkUrl)
                .build();

        ShareApi.share(linkContent, null);
        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

Everything works fine and the publication is made whit no errors. The only issue is that the image will not show on the dialog preview.
After reading the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images), (in the Pre-caching images section) it says that to solve this you need to do the following

> Use og:image:width and og:image:height Open Graph tags. Using these
>   tags will specify the image to the crawler so that it can render it
>   immediately without having to asynchronously.

How can I include these OG tags in the ShareDialog image so it renders properly?
I'm using last `Facebook SDK 4.7`

Comment: You can not include OG tags there; they have to be in the HTML code of the URL that gets shared.

Comment: I see. I'll dig into that thanks a lot CBroe